# JSP download - application/octet-stream

Tags: java, jsp, download, content-type, byte

I have a page in JSP that list some file that could be downloaded by a user.
Thoses files are not on the local server, they are on a remote file server.

When the user click to download a file, the webserver connect via TCP to the file server. The web server download the file and create a HTTP response for the client.

Here is my code:

```
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="sun.misc.Request"%>
<%@page import="listing.ClientTCPStockage"%>
<%@page import="java.net.InetAddress"%>

<%
out.clearBuffer();

String nomFichier = request.getParameter("fichier");
String adresseStockage = request.getParameter("adresseStockage");

ClientTCPStockage clientStockage = new ClientTCPStockage(InetAddress.getByName(adresseStockage), 2004);
byte donneeFichier[] = clientStockage.getDonneesFichier(nomFichier);

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + nomFichier + "\"");
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream;");
response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(donneeFichier.length));

for(int i = 0; i < donneeFichier.length; i++){
    out.write(donneeFichier[i]);
}
%>
```

This is working perfectly fine for text-based file, like .csv or normal .txt 
but It doesnt work for other type like .mp3 or .jpeg.. the files end up corrupt.

I think there is a problem with my encoding but I can't find where..

Here is the HTTP Header response:

```
HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.mp3"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
Content-Length: 5387668
Date: Sun, 20 Dec 2009 18:52:18 GMT
```

Thanks.

Comment: ClientTCPStockage connect to the file server and grab the file as a byteArray. At this point the content is valid because when I tries to put it back on the hard drive as a file it works perfectly. 

Data get corrupt when I output it as a HTTP response

Comment: Probably a dup: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776142/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response/1776161#1776161 for the perils of writing to an `OutputStream` from a JSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If forced to use jsp (and not a servlet), you may take a look at [this how-to](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0366.html)

It uses the `ServletOutputStream`, which is more appropriate for binary content, rather than a `JspWriter`.

Also note the settings for trimming the whitespaces.

Comment: Ah yes, the `out` unintuitively refers to the `Writer`, not the `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 4):

JSP is a view technology. Everything outside the scriptlets `<% %>` will be **printed** to the response, including whitespace characters such as newlines. It would surely corrupt binary files.

You could trim the whitespace in the JSP file, but scriptlets are discouraged since a decade and nowadays considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831238/jsp-for-business-layer/1832327#1832327). Raw Java code belongs in Java classes, not in JSP files. The real solution is to use a `Servlet` for this.

Create a class which `extends HttpServlet`, implement the `doGet()` method, move the Java code from the JSP file into this method, map this servlet on a certain `url-pattern` and your problem should disappear. You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html) a *basic* example of such a servlet.

Apart from this problem is that you're storing the entire file in a `byte[]` instead in an `InputStream`. I am not sure what your `ClientTCPStockage` actually is doing, but I'd suggest to fix that as well. This because every `byte` of a `byte[]` costs effectively one byte of JVM's memory. Imagine that you have 128MB of JVM memory and that there are more than 10 users concurrently running this piece code with a file of larger than 12.8MB. Yes, `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: +1 I didn't catch the whitespace. Although I agree that the Servlet would be cleaner and the best practice, let's at least mention that the OP could simply squish the first 6 lines together like this `<%@page language="java"%><%@page import="sun.misc.Request"%><%@page import="listing.ClientTCPStockage"%><%@page import="java.net.InetAddress"%><%` and the jsp page would probably work as is. Some days you've just gotta get things done without having to refactor all your jsps into Servlets. :)

Comment: Also, be sure there is no trailing whitespace at the end of the file after the `%>`.

Comment: white space should not be an issue because I call out.clearBuffer() at the start

Comment: I would like to use servlet but I can't, this is a school project, and I have to use classic JSP. I know I should use MVC, servlet, grails... But I can't !

Comment: @Hubert Perron: `clearBuffer()` won't clear anything that's already been flushed to the client. And it won't throw any Exception either (`clear()` will). Squishing lines 1-6 together is at least worth a try. Let us know if it works.

Comment: Get rid of **any** whitespace outside the `<% %>` things (spaces, newlines, etc) and also ensure that your JSP isn't saved with a BOM.

Comment: @Asaph Just tried it and the files are still corrupt. When I look at the file with an editor some char seem to be replaced.. 

Normal source file: 
PØ+«¸š6Ñ$u$¦•1å§YI*ÅÌf±â‘å7tê1õ‚^o

After HTTP download:
P?+???6?$u$??1??YI*??f????7t?1??^o

Comment: @BalusC I'm sure the is no whitespace/newlines lefts. How can I check for the BOM ?

Comment: @Hubert: Your binary files are been read or written as characters. Use InputStream/OutputStream instead of Reader/Writer.