# Java EE PDF Viewer

Tags: jsf, pdf, icefaces, pdf-viewer, icepdf

I have a `JSF/Icefaces` project and currently I'm looking for a pdf viewer. There is a library called `icepdf` and it seems to be a `Swing` library.

Are there any other Java based libraries for viewing pdf files in the web browser?

Can we use the `icepdf` solution as an applet in my app?

Comment: There is some related information here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746283/how-do-i-display-a-pdf-onto-a-jsf-page

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at solutions like PDF.js