# JSP: "getOutputStream() has already been called for this response" get exception while display image on screen

Tags: java, sql, jsp, exception

I am getting exception while fatch image from database and display image on screen. Please help me to solve this error..

```
int questionid ;
Connection conn = null;
conn= new DBFunction().getconnect();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

questionid=4;

try
{  

    conn.setAutoCommit (false);  

    // get the image from the database
    Blob img ;
    byte[] imgData = null ;

    String  req = "Select img From questionlist Where queid = " + questionid ;
    ResultSet rset  = stmt.executeQuery ( req ); 

    while (rset.next ())
    {    
      img = rset.getBlob("img");
      imgData = img.getBytes(1,(int)img.length());
    }    
        // display the image
       response.reset();
       response.setContentType("image/gif");

       OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();

        o.write(imgData);
        o.flush(); 
        o.close();
}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Let me know where am i wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776142/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response

Answer (score 0):

It is not the better practice to write the `java` codes inside jsp as jsp calls `printWriter` by default. Scriptlets are not advised over decades . try moving the code into a java file , preferably a servlet.

Also it is not better option to store images into Database , try to use the diskspace instead. As far as your question try `out.clear()`

see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)