# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response error

Tags: java, jsp, web, servlet-3.0

Exception :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

root cause :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:627)
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:215)
javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:190)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:123)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
org.apache.jsp.DownloadResume_jsp._jspService(DownloadResume_jsp.java:91)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: And your code is ...?

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776142/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response

Answer (score 0):

I think I also got this error when I was working with jasper reports with Struts.
What happen was after creating the report I still returned a value(null) from the Action class(Servlet/Controller). The issue is, the report was set to the HTTPResponse and it is generated and I returned the response from the Action class again.
I just commented the return part from the Action class and then it worked.
Hope this will solve your issue.
Thanks.