# ShoppingCart servlet giving error?

Tags: java, servlets

I am not able to find what is wrong with my webApp. This is my first project and i'm kinda stuck. All i know is that something is going wrong in `ShoppingCart.java` whenever i click add to cart in `index.html` it gives me a error code of series 500 i tried to look into console but didn't understand it fully. It is very simple code please tell me if you see something..

`index.html`

```html
<table border="1px">
    <th>PIZZA NAME</th>     <th>PRICE</th>  <th>ADD TO CART</th>
    <form action="addToCart">
        <tr>
             <td> Peppereno</td>
             <td> 20$ </td> 
             <td align="center"> 
               <input type="hidden" name="name" value="peppereno"/>
               <input type="hidden" name="price" value="20"/>
               <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
             </td>
        </tr>    
    </form>

    <form action="addToCart">
         <tr>
              <td> Barbeque</td>
              <td> 10$</td>
              <td align="center">
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="barbeque">
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="10"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
              </td>

         </tr> 
    </form>    

    <form action="addToCart">
         <tr>
             <td> Farmhouse</td>
             <td> 35$ </td>
             <td align="center">
                 <input type="hidden" name="name" value="farmhouse"/>
                 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="35"/>
                 <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
             </td>
    </form>
</table>
```

`Cart.java`

```
package com.cart;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Cart {
    HashMap<String, Integer> cartItems;

    public Cart() {
        cartItems = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void addToCart(String item, Integer price) {
        cartItems.put(item, price);
    }

    public void deleteFromCart(String item) {
        cartItems.remove(item);
    }
}
```

`ShoppingCart.java`

```
package com.cartServlet;

import com.cart.*;

@WebServlet("/ShoppingCart")
public class ShoppingCart extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ShoppingCart() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Cart shoppingCart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("cart");
        if (shoppingCart == null) {
            shoppingCart = new Cart();
            session.setAttribute("cart", shoppingCart);
        }
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        Integer price = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price"));
        shoppingCart.addToCart(name, price);
        session.setAttribute("cart", shoppingCart);

        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("response.html");
        dispatch.include(request, response);

        HashMap<String, Integer> items = shoppingCart.getItems();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<table border='1px'>");

        for (String key : items.keySet()) {
            out.println("<tr><td>" + key + " - </td><td>" + "$" + items.get(key) + "</td></tr>");
        }

        out.println("</table>");
    }
}
```

`response.html`

```html
<h3>Pizza successfully added to the cart</h3>
<form action="index.html">
Add more pizza to cart<input type ="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
<h2>Cart</h2>
```

`web.xml`

```xml
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.cartServlet.ShoppingCart</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addToCart</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

`logFile`

```
 Mar 30, 2016 7:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve   invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [abc] in context with path      [/ShoppingCart] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:679)
    at   org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
    at com.cartServlet.ServletCart.doGet(ServletCart.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please provide the exception from the logfile.

Comment: @tak3shi i've added the logfile please have a look on it....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using @WebServlet("/ShoppingCart") due to which the url pattern becomes http://host:port/ShoppingCart instead of http://host:port/addToCart
So i suggest you to change the action in your html with

`<form action="ShoppingCart">
     <tr>
         <td> Farmhouse</td>
         <td> 35$ </td>
         <td align="center">
             <input type="hidden" name="name" value="farmhouse"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="price" value="35"/>
             <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
         </td>
</form>`

Hope this will work for you!! :)

Comment: hello abhishek, thanks for your answer but ShoppingCart you are mentioning is actaully the name of this web App.. I think you might get confused because i also gave my servlet the same name...

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Servlets and JSP´s. Think about what technology you really need.
You can combine this technologies if you want. Here is described how to do it:
[getOutputStream() has already been called for this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776142/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response)